# I have two different buttons, but the CSS applies the hover color of the second HTML button to the first. How do you fix this?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have two different color buttons. When I tried, it makes the hover color for ".hicodestled" the hover color of ".styled. Also, the ".hicodestled" button is just idle when hovering on it. When trying to add different classes, it still does not distinguish the two buttons.

```css
.styled {
  float: right;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 220, 0, 1);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.styled:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
}

.styled:active {
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6), inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.hicodestled {
  float: right;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 220, 220, 1);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.styled:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 220, 220, 1);
}

.styled:active {
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6), inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://point90.42web.io" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <font color="#ffffff">
    <button class="styled" type="button">
    <b>Back up</b>
</button>
    <button class="hicodestled" type="button">
    <b>View code</b>
</button>
  </font>
</a>
```

Edit: I now realize this is a garbage question as I was not looking at the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be a problem with the overwriting of the hicodestled button class. In the code below i changed the hover color and replaced the second styled button declaration for hicodestled. The code works as it should now but the colors are currently set to red and a darker shade of green for testing purposes. I suggest you change those according to your needs.

```
   <style>
  .styled {
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 220, 0, 1);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top left,
                                      rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),
                                      rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 30%,
                                      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6),
                inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.styled:hover {
    background-color: red
}

.styled:active {
    box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6),
                inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
  
    .hicodestled {
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 220, 220, 1);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top left,
                                      rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),
                                      rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 30%,
                                      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6),
                inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.hicodestled:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.hicodestled:active {
    box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6),
                inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
</style>
<a href=http://point90.42web.io style=text-decoration:none><font color=#ffffff>
  <button class="styled"
        type="button">
    <b>Back up</b>
</button>
    <button class="hicodestled"
        type="button">
    <b>View code</b>
</button>
</font></a>
```